# Modules and Services in Sitefinity administration

Tags: c#, .net, module, content-management-system, sitefinity

How can I create a custom module in administration > modules and services? The explanation given under "Create Custom Module" in https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/overview-custom-modules is somewhat similar to my requirement but I couldn't find any documentation on how to create it. 
I want to add the logic for the actions the module will perform when getting added to a Sitefinity CMS site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a custom module? That's normally created with code.

Most common thing people need is a **custom content type**, aka Dynamic Module.

This is created from Administration > Module Builder

This will create a module for you and then you can see it under Modules and Services.

**Update**: You can download Sitefinity Thunder from here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-443.ProgressSitefinityThunder

It comes with many Visual Studio project templates, one of which is a Custom Module template. You can use that to create the necessary module.

Comment: Dynamic Module was the one we used to follow. But in this case, I really need custom modules. I did not find any document which explains "How to create a custom module".

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Thank you for your help @Veselin. But I have tried this one too. It says "Your Sitefinity version 11.2.6900.0 is not supported" when trying to install thunder module to my project. After a few google search, I think Sitefinity has stopped its support for thunder after their version 10.2.

Comment: What you can do then is to download v.10.2 and create a test site. Then add a new module via Visual Studio to that site. Finally, copy all the files for that module to the new project - it might work